# Having issues with SQL JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

Could someone help me make this better?
I am trying to get all rows from both tables where the sender and recipient matches the user_id and trashed has the value of 1;
This is what I've done. But my code is returning only one row, whereas there are at least two rows: one on each table.
Thanks.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * 
          FROM inbox 
          JOIN outbox 
            ON inbox.recipient = outbox.sender 
               AND 
               inbox.trashed = outbox.trashed 
         WHERE inbox.recipient = '$user_id' 
               AND 
               inbox.trashed = '1'"
```

Comment: Are you sure `...AND inbox.trashed = outbox.trashed WHERE...` should be there? If you only want to have everything where the two recipents match and inbox.trashed = 1 you should use only these cinditions, so `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM inbox JOIN outbox ON inbox.recipient = 
outbox.sender WHERE 
inbox.recipient = '$user_id' AND inbox.trashed = '1'"`

Comment: If you want to select similar rows from different tables, you should probably use a `UNION` instead of a `JOIN`.

Comment: If there is 1 record in each table that matches the conditions, then your query will return a single row in the resultset because join places the matching records next to each other into a single row.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Matei. That worked perfectly. All thanks to StackOverflow.com

Comment: It feels great when you receive thanks for nothing :) I think you meant @TobiasF. ?